# Ansible как запустить скрип от другого пользователя, если плейбук начат root?

Tags: ansible

Доброй ночи,

Составляю роль для установки Rust.

Весь плейбук запущен под **become_user = root**

Игра фейлится после выполнения последнего таска, где нужно запустить скачаный скрипт от пользователя который был до become_user:

iwi.yml

```
---

- hosts: localhost
  become: True
  become_method: su
  become_user: root
  roles:
    - iwi-sys-upgrade-install
    - iwi-lang-rust
```

iwi-lang-rast/tasks/main.yml

```
---

- name: "download rustup-init.sh from https://www.rustup.rs"
  get_url:
    url: https://sh.rustup.rs
    dest: /tmp/rustup-init.sh
    mode: 0755

- name: "install Rust with /tmp/rustup-init.sh, run by {{ ansible_user_id }}"
  become: yes
  become_user: {{ ansible_user_id }}
  shell: '/tmp/rustup-init.sh -y'
```

Почемуто выдает синтаксическую ошибку:

```
ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.


The error appears to have been in '/home/Sharlatan/Projects/prj/iwi/Ansible/roles/iwi-lang-rust/tasks/main.yml': line 11, column 17, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

  become: yes
  become_user: {{ ansible_user_id }}
                ^ here
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Кавычки добавьте:

```
become_user: "{{ ansible_user_id }}"
```

Подробности в [доках](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/YAMLSyntax.html#gotchas). Без `"` Ansible думает, что `{` - это словарик.

Comment: Да, методом тыка уже обнаружил это, спасибо за ответ.